# ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-3.0

I am trying to execute this command in azure vsts release pipeline as postdeployment action inline script:

```
powershell -command "&{
 $json = Get-Content '.\appsettings.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json;
 $data = '{"allowedUrls" : [{ "host" : "someUrl","protocol" : "https"},{ "host":"localhost:44394","protocol" : "https"}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json;
 $json.allowedUrls = $data.allowedUrls;
 $json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 32 | Set-Content '.\appsettings.json'; 
 }"
```

it works locally when I run this in powershell but on azure i got:

```
 Standard error from script: 
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5939074Z ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: someUrl.
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5939545Z At line:1 char:286
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5940773Z + ...  host:localhost:44394,protocol : https}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json; Write- ...
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5941450Z +                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5942156Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentEx 
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5942641Z    ception
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5943137Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co 
2020-06-09T08:27:08.5943649Z    mmands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

what might be wrong ?

when escaped string like that `$data = '{`"allowedUrls`" : [{`"host`" :`"someUrl`",`"protocol`" :`"https`"},{`"host`":`"localhost:44394`",`"protocol`" :`"https`"}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json;`

I got

```
Standard error from script: 
2020-06-09T09:13:30.3130099Z ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (4): [{ 
2020-06-09T09:13:30.3131022Z `host` : `someUrl`,`protocol` : `https`},{ `host`:`localhost:44394`,`protocol` 
2020-06-09T09:13:30.3131695Z : `https`}]
2020-06-09T09:13:30.3132284Z At line:1 char:175
2020-06-09T09:13:30.3133099Z + ... :`localhost:44394`,`protocol` : `https`}]' | ConvertFrom-Json; $json. ...
```

Comment: what returns this fragment just before the pipe? ```....host:localhost:44394,protocol : https}]}'```

Comment: @Bhaal22 what do you mean ? how i can check that ?

Comment: sorry I misread your script. By reading it carefully, I think you should escape your quotes when building $data. ```$data = '{`"allowedUrls`" : [{ `"host`" : `"someUrl`",`"protocol`" : `"https`"},{ `"host`":`"localhost:44394`",`"protocol`" : `"https`"}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json;```

Comment: @Bhaal22 check updated question, that didn't help

Comment: i made it work this way: ```powershell -command "&{$data = '{"""protocol""" : """https"""}' | ConvertFrom-Json; Write-Output $data}```

Comment: I think the error is about the colon inbetween  `"localhost:44394"`. You may try to escape that character into its UTF-16 code unit `\u003A` to become `"localhost\u003A44394"`

Comment: @theo, I reduced the json data set to only ```{"protocol": "https" } ``` and behavior was the same

Comment: @Bhaal22 That is not the point. The issue is the colon character `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
powershell -command "&{
    $json = Get-Content '.\appsettings.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json;
     $data = '$(additionalAllowedUris)' | ConvertFrom-Json;
     $json.additionalAllowedUris= $data.SyncRoot;
     $json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 32 | Set-Content '.\appsettings.json';
    }"
```

and variable in the pipeline:

```
[{ \"host\" : \"someUrl\",\"protocol\" : \"https\"},{ \"host\":\"localhost:44394\",\"protocol\" : \"https\"},{ \"host\":\"someUrl2\",\"protocol\" : \"https\"}]
```

Comment: ok. script is slightly different now. ```$(additionalAllowedUris)``` comes from the appsetting.json right?

Comment: @Bhaal22 from variables in vsts

Comment: i see. then indeed its better to use them.